# How to add Label.Text to a List<> and have placed labels.text change to list index after event

Tags: c#, list, events, label, forum

**WHAT I HAVE:**

This application places labels in a richtextbox and the labels text is = to the last button and radio button clicked/selected on the forum.

```
List<string> placed_transpose_btn = new List<string>();

    // Create Label at mouse click location with clicked chord's text.
    private void SongSheet_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            Point mouse = PointToClient(MousePosition);
            SongSheet.SendToBack();
            placed_transpose_btn.Add(Current_Cord_Lbl1 + Current_Cord_Lbl2);
            this.Controls.Add(new Label
            {

                Location = new Point(mouse.X - 15, mouse.Y - 5),
                AutoSize = true,
                Text = Current_Cord_Lbl1 + Current_Cord_Lbl2,
                BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White,
                ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red,

            });

           // This is just to see the content of the list
            SongSheet.Text = Convert.ToString(placed_transpose_btn);

      }
```

**OUTPUT:**

*System.Collections.Generic.List'1[System.String]*

(Oh and labels only appear every 2nd click at last clicked location ... why is that?)

**WHAT I NEED:**

- Each label should be added to the placed_transpose_btn list.
- The list content should update according to a tab control on button press event (not attempted this yet as i need the first bit to work first **:D** )
- More questions may follow **:s**

Comment: So you want to add Labels to the Form, overlaying the RTB? (Which names SongSheet?) You realize that that'll make it hard to impossible to edit the RTB..? Which included clicking on it! Also: I f the RTB is formatted in any way you must not change its Text! Use AppensText and Copy & Paste on the Selection instead!

Comment: The text in the RTB will never be changed the idea is to open a text file with OpenFileDialog and then placing labels over the text. But thank you for the heads up ill be sure to make a note of that for future apps.

Comment: What have you tried so far? You dont simply post a *I want this list done*. We dont generate code for you.

Comment: Yuval Itzchakov can you not see the code that i have posted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone posted a answer but deleted it again.

He/She said

```
SongSheet.Text = Convert.ToString(placed_transpose_btn);
```

Is trying to convert the entire string.
I should instead use

```
SongSheet.Text = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, placed_transpose_btn);
```

That said it means i have been adding the Labels to a list all along i was just not accessing it properly.